# "AR/config.h" Not Found

Tags: c, header-files, artoolkit

I am trying to compile the simpleLite.c example from [the ARToolKit5 examples page](https://archive.artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=7_Examples:example_simplelite). If I run the `.app` file, it works fine. I wanted to see if I could modify anything in the file, so I tried to make the file again but I get the errors:

```
./Makefile.in: line 49: ../../include: is a directory
./Makefile.in: line 50: ../../lib: is a directory
./Makefile.in: line 51: ../../bin: is a directory
./Makefile.in: line 54: LIB_DIR: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 54: LIB_DIR: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 54: -L/@SYSTEM@: No such file or directory
./Makefile.in: line 55: -lARgsub_lite: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 56: INC_DIR: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 56: @CFLAG@: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 58: OBJS: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 59: HEADERS: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 61: BIN_DIR: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 61: all:: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 63: BIN_DIR: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 63: OBJS: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 63: /simpleLite:: No such file or directory
./Makefile.in: line 64: BIN_DIR: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 64: OBJS: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 64: LDFLAG: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 64: LIBS: command not found
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'simpleLite.o'
clang: error: no input files
./Makefile.in: line 66: HEADERS: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 66: simpleLite.o:: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 67: CFLAG: command not found
simpleLite.c:68:10: fatal error: 'AR/config.h' file not found
#include <AR/config.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
./Makefile.in: line 69: clean:: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 71: BIN_DIR: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 73: allclean:: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 75: BIN_DIR: command not found
./Makefile.in: line 78: distclean:: command not found
```

The folder contains three files, a `makefile.in`, a `.plist` file and the `.c` source code. The `AR/config.h` folder exists elsewhere in the ARToolKit5 archive (`ARToolKit5/include/AR`).

Normally, I'd assume I need to specify the path from the source folder, but there are also `include` statements like `#  include <GLUT/glut.h>`, which aren't throwing errors.

I'm fairly new/rusty to C development, so I'm not sure what even to look up to fix this issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Do I need to specify the header paths, or is it something less obvious?

Comment: I assume your linker is not complaining about glut.h because it is a system header and there per default in the system location where the linker looks for header files anyways. I assume you are using XCode so you need to tell XCode where to look for the ARToolKit5 header files.

Comment: Yeah, as it turned out the version of Xcode I was using was not compatible with the version of ARToolkit. If you downgrade Xcode to 7.x, it should work. I actually move to a different AR platform though, so I can't verify the result. Thank you.

Comment: You are probably right ARToolKit5 never got an update to the latest XCode version. That has something todo with Apple removing the support for some video rendering library (can't recall the name right now). It is fixed in ARToolKit6, though. Out of curiosity with AR platform are you using now?

Comment: I'm using Vuforia on Unity. I'm thinking it can do what I want (this is just for a school project), but I'm not entirely sure yet. I also looked at Wikitude which looked decent. ARCore and ARKit look like the best, assuming you have the relevant hardware.